# Make hover CSS dropdowns clickable with JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a website layout currently using a css hover dropdown menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/egvvh5yq/

So far this is fully functional for me, however, I would like to make the drop down click activated.  When clicked, the menu stays dropped down until clicked out of, or onto a new category. The Hover state also remains.

I have not been able to achieve this yet, jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/mcLh5gch/5/

I can achieve a simple dropdown with one link using javascript below, but not with the formatting I would like (rows and columns in dropdown).

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        // Clickable Dropdown
        $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
        $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
        $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
            $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
            $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
            if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
                $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
                $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
.click-nav {margin:10px auto;width:171px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.click-nav ul {position:relative;font-weight:200;}
.click-nav ul li {position:left;list-style:none;cursor:pointer;}
.click-nav ul li ul {position:absolute;left:0;right:0;}
.click-nav ul .clicker {position:relative;color:#696969; text-align: center;width:171px;height:75px;line-height:75px;padding:0px; 
background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #90383b 50%, #90383b );
background-size: 100% 202%;
}
#mainmenu { transition: all 0.2s ease;animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover {background-position: 100% 100%;animation: up-bump 0.4s ease; color:#FFF}
.click-nav ul .active {background-position: 100% 100%;color:#FFF}
.click-nav ul li a {display:block;background:#FFF;color:#333;text-decoration:none;padding:8px;width:155px;}
#sub:hover{background:#90383b; color:#FFF}

/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {display:none;}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {display:block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="click-nav">
<ul class="no-js">
<li>
  <a href="#" id="mainmenu" class="clicker">Box 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 4</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 5</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 6</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 7</a></li>
    <li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 8</a></li>
<li><a id="sub" href="#">Space 9</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

All and all I am asking for help to achieve a click dropdown with the hover menu I have now.  My attempt can be reviewed, but it is difficult for me to pin down whats wrong.  I'm new at this!

Answer (score 0):

Use the .on() function for this type of events.
Check it out:

```
   $(function() {
    // Clickable Dropdown
    $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
        $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


   $(".greybox").on("click", "li", function(){
        alert("Item Clicked");
       /*
        if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
            alert('test');
            $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp(slow);
            $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
        }*/
   });


});
```

Comment: Sarom,  I believe the code I posted works, see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxzsjLcL/4/

However, I would really like that dropdown to be formatted in rows and columns with the top border as well. I need to achieve the same visual effect as the hovers show, whichever method I can.  I also need to know how this can be done for separate boxes.

Comment: I have not tried yours in jsfiddle yet, will that allow multiple dropdown buttons?

Comment: I have attempted this, but it does not function fully while hovering off the link.